# Establecer progreso a partir de comprobaciones Splash-Screen

Tags: android, sqlite

Como puedo sustituir el CountDownTimer que se encarga de simular el progreso de el progress bar a esta forma:

Mi idea es que compruebe si existe las cuatro tablas de la base de datos que debe de tener la aplicación creada y que ademas verifique la existencia de datos dentro de cada una de ellas. A medida que valla comprobando las existencias, que la barra valla incrementandose hasta que compruebe que todo esta correcto y llegue al 100% y pase a la actividad principal

Esquema de clases:

[image: Esquema]

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

// Set the duration of the splash screen
public ProgressBar splash_screenProgressBar;
public int MAX_VALUE = 30;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set portrait orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    splash_screenProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_screenProgressBar);
    splash_screenProgressBar.setMax(MAX_VALUE);

    new CountDownTimer(3000, 100) {

        int progreso = 1; // Variable que va a ir aumentando del progreso
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            splash_screenProgressBar.setProgress(progreso);
            progreso += (1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            splash_screenProgressBar.setProgress(MAX_VALUE);

            // Start the next activity
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);

            // Close the activity so the user won't able to go back this activity pressing Back button
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}

}
```

La clase que se encarga de crear la base de datos, esta es la clase que se encarga de una de las tablas. Las demas clases son similares.

```
public class EstadoSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public EstadoSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //Se ejecuta las sentencias SQL de creación de las tablas
    String query="CREATE TABLE ESTADO (id_estado INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, situacion BOOLEAN);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //En caso de cambio de version se ejecutaria esta bloque de codigo
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ESTADO;");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ESTADO (id_estado INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, situacion BOOLEAN);");
}

//Metodo que me permite abrir la tabla
public void abrirBDEstado(){
    this.getWritableDatabase();
}

//Metodo que me permite cerrar la tabla
public void cerrarBDEstado(){
    this.close();
}

//Metodo que me permite realizar insert en la tabla
public void insertarEstado(boolean situacion){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("situacion", situacion);
    this.getWritableDatabase().insert("valor", null, valores);
}

//Metodo que me permite realizar update en la tabla
public void modificarEstado(boolean situacion){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("situacion", situacion);
    this.getWritableDatabase().update("estado", valores, "id_estado = ?",new String[] {"1"});
}
}
```

Comment: Hay bastante material de sobre SplashScreen comprueba a ver si te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=splashscreen

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un incrementador del progreso, es decir tu SplashScreen es de 4 pasos

`int steps = 0`

Por cada validación de tabla incrementa el valor `steps`

puedes hacer un `Runable` que cada segundo:

dependiendo del valor `step` con los pasos totales, puedes determinar que `porciento` de carga está realizada, puedes establecer el valor del progressbar de 0 a 100 o bien de 0 a totalpasos.
Chequea el valor del `step` si ha llegado a 4, cargue la pantalla principal.

En pseudo código

```
Iniciar SplashScreen step = 0; stepMax = 4;
Asyntask
 Comprobar Tabla1
    Si no existe Crearla
    step++;
 ...

 Cada segundo
 Actualizar UI barra 0=0% y 4=100% ( paso 2*100/4 =50%)
 Comprobar si es step es 4, cargar pantalla principal.
```

Comment: perfecto entiendo la idea pero se me escapa un pequeño apunte. Como verifico la existencia de mi bd. Como seria la sentencia? Un saludo y gracias de antemano

Comment: eso no puedo ayudarte no uso SQL en mi apps, te recomiendo si no es mucho traspaso REALM.IO

Comment: Le echaré un vistazo. La verdad que si tuviera que migrar la bd es muy pequeña no tendría problemas